# odd positioning in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wonder why the letter k is not in the expected place, and why the path to sigma is oddly positioned. what's going on :)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  nat/.style     = {fill=white,draw,circle,minimum size=0.5cm,inner sep=1pt},
}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  nat/.style     = {fill=white,draw,circle,minimum size=0.5cm,inner sep=1pt},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (1,4) -- (1,3)
      node[pos=1,nat] (s) {$\sigma$};
      node[pos=0,nat,above] {$k$};
  \draw (2,0) node[below] {$l$} to[out=90, in=-90] (s);
  \draw (3,0) -- (3,4)
      node[pos=0,below] {$x$}
      node[pos=0.8,nat] (a) {$a$}
      node[pos=1,above] {$x$};
  \draw (1,0) node[below] {$m$} to[bend left] (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a semicolon after {$\sigma$}

Comment: damn semi colon !! that's what happens when you use too much haskell / ocaml and co ! :) thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error was due to a typo as shown in comments.

Comment: justo. non sarà molto utile per altri